# Showing an operator does not admit eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Show the linear operator $T:C(\Re)\to C(\Re)$ given:

$T(u(x))=\int_0^x u(s)ds$ does not admit eigenvalues.

This question is really interesting, but I can't even start it (I'm currently learning how to determine eigenvalues through the $det(M - Id* \lambda) = 0$), but how do I determine the transformation matrix of this?

Comment: You cannot define $\det$ if your space is infinite dimensional. Instead, you should start from definition. A eigenvalue is something that $T u = \lambda u$ for some nonzero $u$. See what can you say about $u$ in this situation.

Comment: Now I see it. I got this expression: $T(u(x))=\int_0^x u(s)ds = \lambda u(x)$, but how do I show there is no $\lambda$ that makes it true?

Comment: Differentiating the expression gives $u(x) =\lambda u'(x)$. Can you find $u$ explicitly?

Comment: Thank you John! You were really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $Tu=\lambda u$, for some nonzero $u$. Let $v=Tu$. Then by the definition of $T$ and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$ v = \lambda v'. $$
Now, we can solve this differential equation: we know that $v(0)=0$ since $\int_0^0 u(s) \, ds = 0$.

But by the uniqueness theorem for ODEs (Picard–Lindelöf, or whatever you want to call it), the unique solution to
$$ v = \lambda v', \quad v(0)=0 $$
is $v(x)=0$. This is true no matter what the value of $\lambda$ is, so there are no such $\lambda$ and no such $v$, and no such $u$. Hence $T$ has no eigenvalues.

Comment: So it's all about the boundary conditions - if you changed it to the operator $T(u(x))=\int_{-\infty}^x u(s)ds$ it would have a continuous spectrum of eigenvalues

Comment: @WW1 Exactly. Boundary conditions are important; we mustn't just throw them away and forget about them!